# Capturar llamada entrante. Android

Tags: android, android-intent

Tengo mi aplicación que utiliza la clase MediaPlayer, necesito que cuando entre una llamada el sonido quede en mute, pero cuando la app pasa a segundo plano (cuando se presiona el botón home por ejemplo) siga la reproducción del audio.

```
   public static class ReceptorLlamadas extends BroadcastReceiver {
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       call(context);
   }

   private void call(Context context) {
       PhoneCallListener phoneListener = new PhoneCallListener();
       TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
       telephonyManager.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
   }

   private class PhoneCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {
       public boolean isPhoneCalling = false;
       Boolean wasRinging = false;

       @Override
       public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
           if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
               // phone ringing
              //Aquí ya detectas que el teléfono esta recibiendo una llamada entrante

           }
           if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
               // active
               isPhoneCalling = true;
               if (mPlayer != null && mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                   mPlayer.setVolume(0,0);
               }
           }

           if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {

               isPhoneCalling = false;
           }

       }
   }
```

y esto agregué al manifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".MainActivity$ReceptorLlamadas">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con `TelephonyManager` puedes recoger los diferentes estados del teléfono:

```
 public class prueba extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    call(context);
}

private void call(Context context) {
    PhoneCallListener phoneListener = new PhoneCallListener();
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephonyManager.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}

private class PhoneCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    public boolean isPhoneCalling = false;
    Boolean wasRinging = false;

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
            // phone ringing
            //Aquí ya detectas que el teléfono esta recibiendo una llamada entrante
        }

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
            // active
            isPhoneCalling = true;
        }

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {

            isPhoneCalling = false;
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: muchas gracias, pero me quedó una duda, donde llamo a call()?

Comment: Desde el `onReceive` que es donde quieres hacer la comprobación del estado

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero me figura un error: has no zero argument constructor.

Comment: Modifiqué la pregunta agregando mi nuevo código.

Comment: prueba poniendo el código del call() dentro del onReceive en vez de llamar a la función , pon el código que te da para verlo.

Comment: agregué una imagen a mi pregunta para que veas el error que me figura al subir el codigo a onReceive

Comment: la función la pones fuera y la llamas desde el  onReceive , en la imagen veo que has metido toda la función dentro del onReceive

Comment: estimado, modifiqué nuevamente mi pregunta agregando el código que tengo actualmente, además el log del error, porque al entrar una llamada se origina ese error.

Comment: La clase principal es ReceptorLlamadas ?, si es así tienes las funciones fuera de la clase principal.Tienen que estar fuera del onReceive pero dentro de la clase principal.

Comment: así lo hice, pero me figura un nuevo error, dejé una imagen, muchas gracias por tus respuestas

Comment: He modificado mi respuesta , prueba y me dices

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43428/discussion-between-fen-dev-and-rodrigo).

Comment: ok, seguimos en el chat

Comment: Me apareció un nuevo error, edité mi pregunta en donde indico el log

Comment: ya solucioné el problema, agregando un if, edité mi pregunta y dejé el codigo con la solucion, muchas gracias.